# Getting an url from an image to display within an html using an API

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm currently trying to display a picture on my html.
I'm using an api from newsapi.org
I have figured out how to show the author, the headline etc. But the picture i cannot display.
I have tried to use an onload function which i'm not sure if i need. Please let me know if it does not matter.
This is what my javascript looks like:

```
const url = "https:newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=xxxxxx";
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    let show = () => {
      let img = document.getElementById("img");
      img.src = data.articles[0].urlToImage;

      let img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
      img1.src = data.articles[1].urlToImage;

      let img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
      img2.src = data.articles[2].urlToImage;

    }
  });
```

This is what my html looks like:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="news.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="img" onload="show()" alt="news">
    <img id="img1" onload="show()" alt="news">
    <img id="img2" onload="show()" alt="news">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"I have tried to use an onload function which i'm not sure if i need."_ - not only do you not need it - it does not even make sense. Your images do not _have_ any `src` initially, so why should they fire a `load` event? Just assign the image sources in your `then((data)` callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test the code myself as you're using an API key that I don't have but it seems like you're returning a `show` function that does not get called anywhere, so nothing happens.

```
const url = "https:newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=xxxxxx";
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
      let img = document.getElementById("img");
      img.src = data.articles[0].urlToImage;

      let img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
      img1.src = data.articles[1].urlToImage;

      let img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
      img2.src = data.articles[2].urlToImage;
  });
```